# Do you drop ʁ when pronouncing die Universität?

Tags: pronunciation

Hi I'm new to German and trying to learn words with their IPA represented pronunciations. About the word `Universität` I get this IPA representation:

```
ˌunivɛʁziˈtɛːt
```

Well in [IPA chart](http://www.yorku.ca/earmstro/ipa/consonants.html) the `ʁ` consonant is stated as the fricative version of `ʀ` and I'm able to pronounce it, but when I listen to Duden's TTS of this word I don't hear any ʀ sound. Can you help me about this?

Comment: The difference is there, it's just hard to hear when you are not used to it. Any German speaker would pronounce "Univesität" und "Universität" in two different ways, no matter how close they are. In the latter case you close your throat for a split second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** There is no fixed distinction between ʁ, ʀ and r in German. Dialects heavily differ but they may also be mixed in one word and any of them is considered correct.

ʁ is described as a fricative version of ʀ, but this mostly applies at beginning of syllables

```
Ich     ←→  Richter
Angst   ←→  Rang
```

and after the  **b/p**, **d/t**, **g/k** consonants pairs, where the ʁ inserts a "backstop" after the preceding consonant.

```
Band    ←→  Brand
Buch    ←→  Bruch  (note: long u in Buch)
Pacht   ←→  Pracht
Punze   ←→  Prunk
Dach    ←→  Drache
Deck    ←→  Dreck
Tag     ←→  trag
Gas     ←→  Gras
Kasse   ←→  krass
```

With the **f** most people would use rather a ʀ instead:

```
Fisch   ←→  frisch
```

That is because this "backstop" ʁ is barely hearable after non-plosives. And that's exactly what you have after a vowel. Vowels are not plosives. The ʁ is barely hearable.

A common tongue twister plays with this:

> Fischers Fritz fischt frische Fische. Frische Fische fischt Fischers Fritz.

Most people will give up because the name *Fritz* sounds weird when **not** pronounced with ʁ, while *frisch* "requires" the ʀ.

In addition, the very common German syllable ending **-er** is pronounced *ɐ*, so people often place this *ɐ* everywhere they spot a stray **-er-**.

Comment: Eh, how does the r in _Fritz_ sound different from the r in _frisch_?

Comment: In *Fritz* the r is nearly unhearable while in *frisch* people tend to emphasize it to make the word distinct from *Fisch*.

Answer (score 5):

In some regional variations of German (especially more to the North of the country) you can replace the "r" in that position by a short "a" directly following the "e" ["univeasiteet"]. However, it is not the best thing to do.

The best thing would be pronouncing it as a very slight tightening of the throat at the end of the "e". Depending from where you are, this might be almost unrecognizable for you (at the beginning). Perhaps that's the reason why you hear the Duden example as leaving the "r" out?

Comment: If you listen closely, you can definitely hear the R but for a non-native speaker that might be difficult indeed.