# How to pronounce the "Fränkel" in German?

Tags: person-names, pronouncation

How to read "[Fränkel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Fraenkel)" in German? Any native German know it?

Now I need to know the exact pronunciation of "Fränkel" to translate it into Chinese from the sound. If you know, please use the [International Phonetic Alphabet for German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA/German) to show how to read it.

By the way, I learn that someone read [ˈfʁa:nkel], but I don't know whether it's right or not.

Comment: I'm sorry but your recent questions are all the equivalent of [translation requests](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/628/6495), just for pronunciation. German and its dialects have quite clear rules for pronunciation. It is much easier than English in this regard. So, I suggest you stop asking for each single name and ask for more general rules. Also, you need to clarify if you are asking for standard German pronunciation or for a specific dialect (Fränkel was born in Munich).

Comment: @Roland I've asked to use  International Phonetic Alphabet for German to show how to read it, i.e., standard German pronunciation.

Comment: OK, please add that information to the question. IPA is also used for dialects.

Comment: @Roland People can give both standard and dialect only if they speak it clearly. So I think it's not necessary to ask more although I possibly choose the standard one. Anyway, thanks for your advice.

Comment: I don't think this type of question is a good fit for the site, as the answer wouldn't even have to be a sentence, just a transcription [fʁ...]. There is no problem to be solved, nothing to be explained.

Comment: If the main goal it to transliterate the name into Chinese, why not just look it up on [Chinese Wikipedia](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%9A%E4%BC%AF%E6%8B%89%E7%BD%95%C2%B7%E5%BC%97%E5%85%B0%E5%85%8B%E5%B0%94)?

Comment: @Roland please have a look at and engage with the discussion on meta: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/how-to-pronounce-fragen

Comment: @RDBury  It's not a good idea to look it up in Chinese Wikipedia: (1) it's not a Chinese question; (2) there are several Chinese transliterations for "Fränkel" which I can't determine is most close to the sound of "Fränkel"; (3) my Chinese is very very good while what I lack is the exact sound of "Fränkel".

Comment: @DavidVogt The above post also replies to you to some extent. It's very strange if we can't ask pronunciations for words in a language on a site about a language. Also the site has large amounts of questions which ask for exact pronunciations.

Comment: Asking for a single-word pronunciation of a name is different than asking for a single-word translation: Translations can be looked up in dictionaries, name pronunciations can't. If the name is a name of a relevant person, I could also see how the question has value to others, and hence is of general insterest. So, I think the analogy to translation requests is significantly flawed.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach There are several Chinese transliterations for "Fränkel" (for examples, 弗兰克尔, 弗兰克, 弗伦克尔, 弗伦克, 弗兰凯, 弗伦凯) which I can't determine is most close to the sound of "Fränkel". Although in China, there are books for transliterations for names, but we, especially scholars, don't use them because many of the translating names transliterated from a wrong sound for some historical reasons. What I do now is to get the exact and right sound, and then transliterate it into a right one. This case is very different from those in other languages. So let's be open to all kinds of questions.

Comment: Also, the exact sounds for the names that I asked usually can't be found on the internet since I've searched them before asking here.

Comment: @M.Logic My comment was referring to the initial comment of Roland. I meant to express that I believe that the question is a good fit for this site.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach I see. Thanks for your open minds. By the way, how to pronounce your surname "Scholbach"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably ['frɛŋk<sup>h</sup>ǝl] or ['frɛŋkl] (the first version is more formal). Definitely not with [a:].

Comment: Maybe also [ˈfʁɛŋkl], but the 'r' sounds vary a lot by region anyway (see also https://german.stackexchange.com/a/37978/5398)